# 'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero when setting textview's text in MonoDroid

Tags: android, xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I'm using MvvmCross with MonoDroid.

In a timer in the viewmodel, every minute I call `RaisePropertyChanged("MinutesRemaining")` - `MinutesRemaining` being an integer specifying the duration in minutes until the current entry ends (and yes, this is called on the UI thread!).

`MinutesRemaining` is bound to a `TextView` using MvvmCross.

Until the `4.10.1` update from Xamarin, the app would just crash completely with no error message printed to the trace - it's now breaking correctly when debugging and giving the below error when invoking the `PropertyChanged` event:

```
MvxBind:Error:281.24 Problem seen during binding execution for binding Text for MinutesRemaining - problem ArgumentException: 'jobject' must not be IntPtr.Zero.
Parameter name: jobject
  at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallVoidMethod (IntPtr jobject, IntPtr jmethod, Android.Runtime.JValue[] parms) [0x00010] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/9d03ce3e/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/src/Runtime/JNIEnv.g.cs:499 
  at Android.Widget.TextView.set_TextFormatted (ICharSequence value) [0x00034] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/9d03ce3e/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-14/src/generated/Android.Widget.TextView.cs:1814 
  at Android.Widget.TextView.set_Text (System.String value) [0x00013] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/monodroid-mlion-monodroid-4.10.1-branch/9d03ce3e/source/monodroid/src/Mono.Android/platforms/android-14/src/generated/Android.Widget.TextView.cs:1823 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid.Target.MvxTextViewTextTargetBinding.SetValueImpl (System.Object target, System.Object toSet) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.Target.MvxConvertingTargetBinding.SetValue (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Bindings.MvxFullBinding.UpdateTargetFromSource (System.Object value) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

It binds correctly the first time - it's only on subsequent `RaisePropertyChanged` calls that this occurs. The same code also works on Windows 8 and Windows Phone.

#### Update

Using JavaFinalise in the adapter used for the scenario above fixed the problem (found here: [MVVMCross Binding Crashes Android Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659458/mvvmcross-binding-crashes-android-application)). The problem I have now is the same result, but where the first view in an adapter is bound to a property in the parent view model (not the item).

Code used to bind is as follows:

```
public class SubjectFilterAdapter : MvxAdapter {
    private EntityListFragment<TEntity, TViewModel> _owner;

    public SubjectFilterAdapter(Context context, EntityListFragment<TEntity, TViewModel> owner) : base(context, (IMvxAndroidBindingContext)owner.BindingContext) {

        _owner = owner;
    }

    protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object dataContext, int templateId) {
        var view = base.GetBindableView(convertView, dataContext, templateId);

        if (templateId == ItemTemplateId && GetPosition(dataContext) == 0) {
            var set = _owner.CreateBindingSet<EntityListFragment<TEntity, TViewModel>, TViewModel>();

            set.Bind(view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.SelectedScheduleText))
                .To(x => x.SelectedScheduleText).WithClearBindingKey("SelectedScheduleTextFilterBinding");

            set.Apply();
        }

        return view;
    }

    protected override void JavaFinalize() {
        if (this.BindingContext != null)
            this.BindingContext.ClearAllBindings();
        base.JavaFinalize();
    }
}
```

It works correctly to begin with (for the first couple of changes) but after that the above exception is thrown. Using MvvmCross `3.0.14-beta3`.

Thanks!

Comment: Might be related to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659458/mvvmcross-binding-crashes-android-application

Comment: Is this problem occuring in a list? Or in some other control? Are you seeing this in the latest code - e.g. the 3.0.14-beta3 binaries? (This doesn't include the JavaFinalize from that linked question, but does include other changes around lists)

Comment: JavaFinalize fixed one of them - the other it hasn't (binding to a text view inside an adapter using the view model not the datacontext for that item). I've updated to the beta3 binaries, problem still persists :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By mixing listitem/cell binding contexts with the parent context you're entering into quite an advanced area.

To help try to explain/debug what you is going on, you need to understand a little about all of the the parent lifecycle, the listitem/cell lifecycle and the lifecycles of the corresponding MvvmCross binding contexts.

At the parent lifecycle level, this is generally an Android `Activity` or `Fragment`. For the sake of simplicity I'll just use `Activity` for the rest of this answer.

This `Activity` has a couple of key lifecycle events

- `OnCreate` is called once only when the `Activity` is first launched
- `OnDestroy` is called once only when the `Activity` will not be shown again.

MvvmCross intercepts these events and:

- within `OnCreate`, it sets a `ViewModel` as the `Activity`'s `DataContext`. User code - normally Xml code inflated within `SetContentView` - then creates bindings. These bindings are stored within the `BindingContext` of the `Activity`
- within `OnDestroy`, MvvmCross destroys all the bindings within that `BindingContext`

In the user interface we're interested in here, the `Activity` owns a `ListView`, and that `ListView` has an `Adapter` set for it. Within this scenario, the `DataContext` for the `ListView` and its `Adapter` is the same as it's parent.

Within the lifetime of the `ListView` the list may need to show lots of items. The items shown at any time may change - both because of user touch actions and because of view model changes. To display these items, the `ListView` asks the `Adapter` for `View`s. For each item it shows the `Adapter` supplies a `View`, and these `View`s may be reused (using the `convertView` parameter). However, sometimes, these `View`s are also not reused - and in this situation it is sometimes possible for the View object to live on in C# even after the Java/Dalvik `View` has been removed and Java finalized.

MvvmCross intercepts the `GetView` calls within its `MvxAdapter`. For each call it returns not just a `View` but moreover and `MvxListItemView`. This is a `View` with an added `BindingContext` - and this allows MvvmCross users to bind each `MvxListItemView` to its list item `DataContext`.

When a `MvxListItemView` is reused, it's simple for MvvmCross to simply change its `DataContext`.

When a `MvxListItemView` is not reused - when it is removed from the UI and then `JavaFinalize`d - MvvmCross intercepts the `OnDetachedFromWindow` event and it uses this to switch the `DataContext` to `null`. It does this on `OnDetachedFromWindow` rather than `JavaFinalize` as the Window call is guaranteed to be made on the UI thread and as it feels (to me) like a cleaner place to do this.

**Note** that some of this behaviour has subtly changed in recent releases - but this description above is correct for v3.0.14

---

With that background in place, what it appears you are currently trying to do is to create a binding for the contents of a `ListItemView` within the `BindingContext` of the `Activity`.

This means that the binding doesn't really have a good understanding of the lifecycle of the `ListItemView` - so the binding can say alive even after the `ListItemView` has been removed from the screen and (maybe) finalized.

To resolve this issue...

- I think the simplest route is to change the DataContext for your listitem. If your ListItemView binding is a simple normal binding - if it contains the MinutesRemaining property - then you shouldn't hit these lifecycle errors.
- You can try the advanced binding found in @Jamie's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20031690/373321) - however, I think this answer doesn't still quite get it right - as I think:

  - it doesn't correctly handle the case where the listitemview is removed/finalised - if the first list item is scrolled off-screen under the current code then I believe you can still see problems. To use Adapter-based code, then I think the Adapter needs to somehow get a callback from the listitemview in the case that that view is removed from the UI or finalised.
  - the `JavaFinalize` in that answer is 'a bit naughty' in that it clears the parent `Activity`s BindingContext during the `Finalize` of the `Adapter`. This is probably OK to do but it shouldn't really be necessary - the `Activity`'s own `OnDestroy` should handle that.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer Stuart! :) - I'll look at adding the additional handling the listitemview.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by updating the above adapter code to:

```
    public class SubjectFilterAdapter : MvxAdapter {
        private EntityListFragment<TEntity, TViewModel> _owner;

        private MvxFluentBindingDescriptionSet<EntityListFragment<TEntity, TViewModel>, TViewModel> _scheduleBindingSet; 

        public SubjectFilterAdapter(Context context, EntityListFragment<TEntity, TViewModel> owner)
            : base(context, (IMvxAndroidBindingContext)owner.BindingContext) {

            _owner = owner;
        }

        protected override View GetBindableView(View convertView, object dataContext, int templateId) {
            var view = base.GetBindableView(convertView, dataContext, templateId);

            if (templateId == ItemTemplateId && GetPosition(dataContext) == 0) {
                if (_scheduleBindingSet != null) {
                    _owner.BindingContext.ClearBindings("SelectedScheduleTextFilterBinding");

                    _scheduleBindingSet = null;
                }

                _scheduleBindingSet = _owner.CreateBindingSet<EntityListFragment<TEntity, TViewModel>, TViewModel>();

                _scheduleBindingSet.Bind(view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.SelectedScheduleText))
                    .To(x => x.SelectedScheduleText).WithClearBindingKey("SelectedScheduleTextFilterBinding");

                _scheduleBindingSet.Apply();
            }

            return view;
        }

        protected override void JavaFinalize() {
            if (this.BindingContext != null)
                this.BindingContext.ClearAllBindings();
            base.JavaFinalize();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think that's still not quite enough... I think you also need to handle the case where the list item view is simply removed from the list. Also clearing the binding context in the adapter finalize is not really a good thing to do. Will answer this fully when I get back from today's travels.

Comment: Thanks Stuart, much appreciated - I'll unmark it as the answer :)