# Best approach to debug native Android crash?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm having random crashes in my Xamarin Android app which result in native Android stacktraces. These stacktraces contain little actual information and I have no idea on how to continue from here.

Some background info: App mainly shows lists of remote (http) images throughout different fragments and activities. App is based on MvvmCross and mainly uses MvxRecyclerview + MvxImageView to show the images. Crashes occur after scrolling and navigating through some lists. Crash mainly happens when returning to an activity on the backstack.

My best guess is that images are being disposed while actually still in use. However, when forcing the images to dispose even when in use, this does not result in a crash but rather in images not showing up. So I'm not sure about my theory anymore.

What can I do to get more information out of this stacktrace?

Stacktrace:

```
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] Attempting native Android stacktrace:
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6fa9dbf]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f94838]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f94247]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f947e8]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f94247]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f947e8]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f94247]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f947e8]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f94247]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f947e8]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f94247]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f947e8]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f94247]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f947e8]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f94247]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f947e8]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f94247]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f947e8]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f94247]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f947e8]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f94247]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f947e8]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f94247]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f947e8]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f94247]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f947e8]
[mono-rt] at ???+0 [0xb6f94247]
[mono-rt] at ZN7android10uirenderer10RenderNode11prepareTreeERNS0_8TreeInfoE+73 [0xb6f946a9]
[mono-rt] at _ZN7android14RootRenderNode11prepareTreeERNS_10uirenderer8TreeInfoE+44 [0xb7671dec]
[mono-rt] at ???+44 [0xb6fadf5a]
[mono-rt] at ???+44 [0xb6fb0010]
[mono-rt] at _ZN7android10uirenderer12renderthread12RenderThread10threadLoopEv+153 [0xb6fb4cc9]
[mono-rt] at _ZN7android6Thread11_threadLoopEPv+398 [0xb74219de]
[mono-rt] at _ZN7android14AndroidRuntime15javaThreadShellEPv+98 [0xb7623c62]
[mono-rt] at _ZN13thread_data_t10trampolineEPKS+122 [0xb74210fa]
[mono-rt] at _ZL15__pthread_startPv+56 [0xb749c218]
[mono-rt] at __start_thread+25 [0xb7497599]
[mono-rt] at __bionic_clone+70 [0xb748e166]
[mono-rt] 
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
[mono-rt] a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
[mono-rt] used by your application.
[mono-rt] =================================================================
[mono-rt] 
[libc] Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x34 in tid 22303 (RenderThread)
```

**Update**

Logcat output contains a bit more info. Previous output was from the Xamarin App console output.

```
09-24 09:40:25.957: A/libc(3495): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x34 in tid 3517 (RenderThread)
09-24 09:40:26.058: I/DEBUG(66): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-24 09:40:26.058: I/DEBUG(66): Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86p/vbox86p:5.1/LMY47D/lc09011706:userdebug/test-keys'
09-24 09:40:26.058: I/DEBUG(66): Revision: '0'
09-24 09:40:26.058: I/DEBUG(66): ABI: 'x86'
09-24 09:40:26.058: I/DEBUG(66): pid: 3495, tid: 3517, name: RenderThread  >>> digipolis.ama.beta.staging <<<
09-24 09:40:26.058: I/DEBUG(66): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x34
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     eax 00000000  ebx b704b508  ecx 00000000  edx 00000000
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     esi a05d130c  edi 9d219b50
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000087  xss 0000007b
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     eip b701adbf  ebp a09f9124  esp a05d12d0  flags 00210246
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66): backtrace:
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #00 pc 0007edbf  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #01 pc 00069838  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #02 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #03 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #04 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #05 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #06 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #07 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #08 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #09 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #10 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #11 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #12 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #13 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #14 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #15 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.066: I/DEBUG(66):     #16 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #17 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #18 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #19 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #20 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #21 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #22 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #23 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #24 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #25 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #26 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #27 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #28 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #29 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #30 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #31 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #32 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #33 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #34 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #35 pc 000697e8  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #36 pc 00069247  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #37 pc 000696a9  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::RenderNode::prepareTree(android::uirenderer::TreeInfo&)+73)
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #38 pc 000bfdec  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::RootRenderNode::prepareTree(android::uirenderer::TreeInfo&)+44)
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #39 pc 00082f5a  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #40 pc 00085010  /system/lib/libhwui.so
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #41 pc 00089cc9  /system/lib/libhwui.so (android::uirenderer::renderthread::RenderThread::threadLoop()+153)
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #42 pc 000169de  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+398)
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #43 pc 00071c62  /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+98)
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #44 pc 000160fa  /system/lib/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+122)
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #45 pc 00021218  /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+56)
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #46 pc 0001c599  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+25)
09-24 09:40:26.067: I/DEBUG(66):     #47 pc 00013166  /system/lib/libc.so (__bionic_clone+70)
09-24 09:40:26.129: I/DEBUG(66): Tombstone written to: /data/tombstones/tombstone_03
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try some of the suggestions in my answer to a previous post. If Visual Studio is not breaking on the exceptions then maybe give #2 a try first. Then, if you can get it to actually break, then #3 might be helpful at that point. Definitely let us know if you find a better solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32655244/3850012

Just to give a brief overview:

#2 Talks about hooking into Android's exception event and setting a breakpoint within it, which allowed me to actually break on exceptions in Visual Studio that, before, would simply crash the app and stop the debugger.

#3 Talks about where to find more helpful information in the exception details, once you are able to correctly break, that tell you which file and line the exception could be coming from.

The answer to the previous post was helpful to me when dealing with Asynchronous operations, but hopefully you can find some use in them as well.

Answer (score -3):

To get crash reports in best and clean way, you can include [parse](https://parse.com/)

or
[google analytics](http://www.google.co.in/analytics/)

in your MainActivity or Application class. These services are free and you can get all crash reports from every phone.

Comment: Will these properly log native crashes like this one? At the moment I'm using Xamarin Insights and this crash isn't even logged. All crashes in managed code are properly logged but this one isn't.

Comment: I'm using Parse in my android apps and my experience has been very good.